# why do i get "Attribute Error: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'"?

Tags: python, string, integer

i need x to be an integer so my next part of code works, but as soon as i remove quotation marks around 0,1 or 2 where it says "making input readable for computer" i get this error message.

```
from random import randint

# Input
print("Rock: R   Paper: P   Scissors: S")
x = input("Please pick your choice: ")

y = randint(0,2)

#Making input readable for computer
if x.lower() == "r":
    x = 0;

if x.lower() == "p":
    x = "1";

if x.lower() == "s":
    x = "2";

print("value entered ", x, "value generated ", y)

if (x == y):
    print("It's a draw!")


# Calculating "Who wins?"
if x == 0 and y == 1:
    print("Computer wins!")
if x == 0 and y == 2:
    print("You won!")

if x == 1 and y == 0:
    print("You won!")
if x == 1 and y == 2:
    print("Computer wins!")

if x == 2 and y == 0:
    print("Computer wins!")
if x == 2 and y == 1:
    print("You won!")
```

Comment: Why not use a different variable for the user generated integer instead of x?

Comment: Python2.x or python3.x?  I assume python3.x?

Comment: Aren't you comparing apples and oranges (`int` and `str`) ? to be clear, `"1" != 1`

Comment: It's python 3, otherwise you get a different error, because of the input() call, and not using raw_input()

Comment: The user is entering a string.  In python 3, input() does just what you want.  In python 2 the input of input() is evaluated.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x

Comment: `(1).lower()` generates this exception - *start* with the information provided by the exception message. Then it's just a matter of finding out *why* the variable evaluates to an integer, as opposed to a string as what is expected.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `elif` here:

```
if x.lower() == "r":
    x = 0

elif x.lower() == "p":
    x = 1

elif x.lower() == "s":
    x = 2
```

Otherwise, all three conditions are evaluated with every run.  Meaning, if the first passes, then `x` will be an integer for the second.

---

Also, you should write your code like this:

```
x = x.lower()  # Put this up here

if x == "r":
    x = 0

elif x == "p":
    x = 1

elif x == "s":
    x = 2
```

That way, you don't call `str.lower` multiple times.

Lastly, Python does not use semicolons.

Comment: I think that you might want to make the latter `"1"` and `"2"` into ints, not strings ...

Comment: @mgilson - Agreed.  I originally was going to leave the OP's code as is...but I think that is what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling x.lower() after you assign x to an integer.

Also, you should probably not use the same variable for the integer and the input string.

Answer (score 0):

iCodez answer is the one, but you should just use the strings, like the following, if you are not using the number conversion to factor your print statement, not both.

**Edit:** Had to change what y was, oops

```
x = raw_input("Please pick your choice: ").lower()
y = choice(['r','p','s'])

if (x == y):
    print("It's a draw!")

# Calculating "Who wins?"
if x == 'r' and y == 'p':
    print("Computer wins!")
elif x == 'r' and y == 's':
    print("You won!")

elif x == 'p' and y == 'r':
    print("You won!")
elif x == 'p' and y == 's':
    print("Computer wins!")

elif x == 's' and y == 'r':
    print("Computer wins!")
elif x == 's' and y == 'p':
    print("You won!")
```

Now if you want to go with the convertion to integer then you could just use this:

```
y = randint(0,2)

if x == "r":
    x = 0

elif x == "p":
    x = 1

elif x == "s":
    x = 2

print ['tie', 'you win', 'they win'][x-y]
```

And semicolons are not needed in Python, but you can still use them if it makes you comfortable.

**Edit:** Just for fun.

```
import random
pick = ['r', 'p', 's']
x = ""
while x not in pick:
    x = str(raw_input("r, p, or s?  ")).lower()
print ['tie', 'y win', 'y win', 'x win', 'x win'][ord(x)-ord(random.choice(pick))]
```

Answer (score 0):

With a couple of dictionaries this code will be short and concise:

```
x_conversion = {'r':0, 'p':1, 's': 2}
x = x_conversion[x.lower()]
```

or list(in this particular case)

```
x_conversion=['r', 'p', 's]
x = x_conversion.index(x.lower())
```

And for winner

```
winner_choice = {(0,1): 'Computer', (1, 2): 'You', ...}
winner = winner_choice[(x, y)]
```

Don't forget try/except and you'll have your results in much shorter and more readable code

Answer (score -2):

Use raw_input() instead of input.

Also this should be:

if x.lower() == "r":
    x = **"0"**

Comment: I just tested the code in python. I don't mean to argue, but it works correctly.

Comment: In python 3 `input()` is the correct function to use.  It replaces `raw_input()`.  `x` should not be a string, it should be an integer, it is the other 2 assignments that are wrong, where `x = "1"` and `x = "2"`.  Those should be `x = 1` and `x = 2` respectively, otherwise the later comparisons are apples to oranges, or strings to integers.